# MySQL : Row size to large - in VB Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I've searched for this subject on the site, and found some tips, but non of them is working for me.

In VB net I am making a table in MySQL (InnoDB), first I will make all the columns and then I fill them with data. But when I am trying to make a table with many columns, I get this error:

> Row size to large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs.

It is crashing when I want more then 196 columns.
I already tried the row format at compressed, but then my maximum is 186 columns (?!). The maximum amount of columns is 300 for my project. I've searched n the config of mySQL workbench 6.3, but can't find the solution. So currently my settings are standard by wizard creation. All the data in the table is TEXT.

Comment: The issue at hand aside - 300 columns smell like a horrible database design.

Comment: Seems like you are missing the whole Relational aspect in the DB.

Comment: I need this many columns. I am download a logging file (txt) from a PLC. This PLC has max 300 datapoint, and this for each minute in the day.

Comment: Try to design two tables, one main table and the second table should have 300 rows per transaction.

Comment: In my opinion I could not use scheme's or relations in my database. Each table is 1 day, in that day there is 1 row for each minute (1440 rows), each column has a sensor with its data. Some projects have 100 sensors, other 300 or in between. The data of the sensor is not predictable, so the data is pretty "raw". I assume MySQL could have more then 198 columns...